# How to create reusable optional mapping with method references?

Tags: java, option-type, method-reference

While I'm trying to use Optional features with method references, it really confused me how to optimize it with reusable code. I think I'm stuck while trying to use all those new features (for me) at the same time i decided to get rid of java-6 style, now I think i can't think simple, i feel that it gets overcomplicated. How can i create

```
List<BooleanExpression> expressionMapping = new ArrayList<>();

    if (request != null) { // request is input parameter, a DTO

        Optional.ofNullable(request.getPlantId())
            .map(campaign.plant.id::contains) // campaign is static created by Querydsl
            .ifPresent(expressionMapping::add);

        Optional.ofNullable(request.getTitle())
            .map(campaign.title::containsIgnoreCase)
            .ifPresent(expressionMapping::add);

        Optional.ofNullable(request.getCampaignNumber())
            .map(this::getLikeWrapped)
            .map(campaign.campaignNumber::like)
            .ifPresent(expressionMapping::add);
... 20 more Optional bunch of code like this
}
```

also having trouble with writing this code with Optional like previous ones:

```
if (request.getLockVehicle() != null) {
            if (request.getLockVehicle()) {
                expressionMapping.add(campaign.lockVehicle.isNotNull());
            } else {
                expressionMapping.add(campaign.lockVehicle.isNull());
            }
        }
```

Comment: Well, if you want to see the benefits you have to actually use `Optional` in your APIs. I mean: until your getters return `null` you'll always have to do the `Optional.ofNullable` stuff wherever you use them. Also: not 100% of the code should use Optional's functional interface. Your second example is probably one case where just using the `if-else` is more readable.

Comment: Then how can i create a function for DRY rule, that i show in the example, Optional, function and adding are repeating.

Comment: Can you provide a Java7- original code of one of the examples above? Like the request.getPlantId()?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about use `enum` to declare all fields from `Request` and use it as common part of the code. I did not check it, this is only to show my approach:

```
public enum RequestField {
    PLANT_ID(Request::getPlantId, (val, campaign) -> campaign.plant.id::contains),
    TITLE(Request::getTitle, (val, campaign) -> campaign.title::containsIgnoreCase),
    CAMPAIGN_NUMBER(Request::getCampaignNumber, (val, campaign) -> campaign.campaignNumber::like),
    // ... more fields here ...
    ;

    private final Function<Request, Optional<Object>> get;
    private final BiFunction<Object, Campaign, BooleanExpression> map;

    RequestField(Function<Request, Object> get, BiFunction<Object, Campaign, BooleanExpression> map) {
        this.get = get.andThen(Optional::ofNullable);
        this.map = map;
    }

    public static List<BooleanExpression> getBooleanExpressions(Request request, Campaign campaign) {
        if (request == null)
            return Collections.emptyList();

        List<BooleanExpression> res = new LinkedList<>();

        for (RequestField field : values())
            field.get.apply(request)
                     .map(r -> field.map.apply(r, campaign))
                     .ifPresent(res::add);

        return res.isEmpty() ? Collections.emptyList() : Collections.unmodifiableList(res);
    }
}
```

And your client code will be looking like:

```
List<BooleanExpression> booleanExpressions = RequestField.getBooleanExpressions(request, campaign);
```

**P.S.**
*Your last code could be look like:*

```
if (request.getLockVehicle() != null)
    expressionMapping.add(request.getLockVehicle() ? campaign.lockVehicle.isNotNull() : campaign.lockVehicle.isNull());
```

Comment: this is pretty nice! 1+

Answer (score 0):

The aim of using `Optional` is informing who is calling that method / parameter that it could be `null`.

In the first part of your code, you are not getting any advantage from this, you are just rewriting some code wrapping it around `Optional` logic but, as you said, without any "reusable" purpose.

A useful way is using it as returning value of a method: for example, if you know that your `title` could be null, you can refactor your getter like

```
public Optional<String> getTitle(){
    return Optional.ofNullable(this.title); //I'm guessing the 'title' variable here
}
```

This will help you: every time you call `getTitle()` , you will know that could be null, because you are obtaining an `Optional<String>` instead of a `String`.

This will bring then you to:

```
request.getTitle().ifPresent(title-> title.doSomething())
// you can also add something like .orElse("anotherStringValue")
```

The second example could be reworked as the first one, making the return of `getLockVehicle()` as `Optional<Boolean>`, even if I suggest here setting that with a default value in your class, probably to `false`... `Optional<Boolean>` is pretty senseless imho

Hope this helps clearing your mind

Comment: `Optional<Boolean>` could be used in 3-valued logic. Although at that point you probably want to implement your own type instead which would support all the usual boolean operations but on your 3-value semantics.

Comment: @GiacomoAlzetta Agree with you, that's a correct point. I added "imho" just because it's my opionion. I really prefer using `enums` in that case, but it's a choice :)

Comment: Is there any problem with DTO fields wrapped with non-serializeble Optionals?